# Brightway ExcelImporter across multiple Excel files

Tags: brightway

The `ExcelImporter` allows importation of activity data:

```
ei = ExcelImporter(fp)
ei.apply_strategies()
ei.match_database(fields=['name'])
```

This works well when multiple activities are defined in the same Excel sheet, and are all for the same database.

Say I have activities defined in two Excel workbooks, `act1.xlsx` and `act2.xlsx` , and that both activities should be imported in the same new database `new_db`. How can they be imported?

I assume the Excel importer is limited to one sheet at a time, and so
`match_database` would return unlinked exchanges for technosphere inputs when importing the first workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to create two instances of `ExcelImporter`, and then simply combine the following attributes (they are all lists):

- `data`
- `database_parameters`
- `project_parameters`

But you should test this to make it works as expected.